# Missing dependencies block on gradle from Project Module

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I am new in Android App Development. I am trying to connect to firebase. I noticed that my project gradle file does not contain dependencies block and when I am trying to insert in manually I get errors. Can someone explain why my gradle files does not contain dependency block

[My Gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVtof.png)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOQ9j.png)

Comment: You can add the `buildscript` block with the `dependencies` inside it, at the top of your `build.gradle`. Then just add the `classpath` you need. See an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72534564/18943404).

Comment: I think that this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70883309/android-studios-project-gradle-file-changed) will help.